# Which one is best solution for future database structure?

Tags: database-design, database-link, denormalization, database-projects

I'm working on a big web application. so i need to create `user_preference_table` it has the marks for every users for each attributes. here attributes are `games` so in the `user_preference_table` i need to store marks for every sports for every users .
for this i have chosen following solution. i have created table like this

`Userid  cricket football tennis baseball` these are columns .

if i want to add another game ! i should alter this table with new column . is this good solution  because i might create more than 1000 games like this. so is it efficient way?
or

I have another idea .

I will create new separate table for every games like following .
table name
`cricket_table`

`userid  marks`
these are columns !

Which one is best solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can create one table for saving `GamesType`

as with two column `GameId`(primary Key) and `GameName`

and in user preference table you can have as `Userid` &`GameId` where `GameId` will be the foreign Key for this table , Let say user has played 5 games, so you can make 5 entry in table `user_preference_table` This can be an efficient way to map Many to Many relation.

The first option as per your question will create so many(1000) columns with so many `NULL` values for every entry.

Other option that you refer is creating a table for each game, can be a choice but again maintaining so many table may be a concern.